# How do I prevent GHCi from "crashing" from this?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I tried running this code, and it ended up making GHCi unusable.
Meaning, the command line (Windows) ended up not responding to any input and simply displaying an empty line.

```
Prelude> b = ["Empty", "Discrete", "Distinct", "Defiant", "Useful", "Good", 
"Imperative", "Safe", "Lawful", "Unpresidented", "Decadent", "Rich", 
"Strong", "Marvelous", "Volatile", "Obtuse", "Acute", "Revolutionary", 
"Frank", "Regular"]
Prelude> length b
20
Prelude> import Data.Char
Prelude Data.Char> a = [ map toLower x | x <- a ]
Prelude Data.Char> a
```

......

Comment: Please format your code with code block and ask a complete question. What is the problem and what is happening?

Comment: Please improve your question. 1) format the code as a snippet; 2) it is not clear where `a` in `length a` comes from; 3) what exactly "unusable" means?

Comment: What do you mean with it ended up making `ghci` unusable?

Comment: I do not understand your formatting concern. The text in this post contains code, which is formatted as code.

Comment: after I formatted it :)

Comment: How come it displayed as code in the post preview window?

Comment: @MarkNeu: it was definitely not. :) Perhaps when you edited the post the second time it was. (I prepended the lines with code with four whitespace chars).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fully expected and normal behaviour.

```
 a = [ map toLower x | x <- a ]
```

is a recursive definition of `a`, where the recursion never ends. Note `a` at both sides of the equals sign. GHCi is not crashing, it just runs this code for always and always, until you interrupt it by pressing Ctrl-C.

Comment: I thought Haskell was lazy. Why is evaluating the definition?

Comment: @MarkNeu Because you have asked to print it by typing it at the interpreter prompt.

Comment: @MarkNeu At a guess: you intended to write `a = [map toLower x | x <- b]`. Note the `b` at the end!

Comment: @n.m. Thank you!

Comment: @MarkNeu The list comprehension needs to get the first element of `a`. The first element of `a` immediately needs the first element of `a` and so on. Since this is the first step, this never gets the chance to produce any output. This can be contrasted with something like `ones = 1 : ones`. First you make a list starting with `1` *then* you need to recurse, so it is productive.

Comment: @DavidYoung Yes, but I thought haskell was lazy. Why is it evaluating the definition?

Comment: @MarkNeu This is the same thing you said in the comment I was replying to (pretty much word-for-word), so I'm not fully sure where you are confused... Maybe you could provide some more detail on what is unclear (maybe what you're expecting vs what's happening)? I can add, though, that it is not evaluating the *definition* (the line that says `a = [ ... ]`), it is evaluating when you just write `a` (you are asking for the value of `a`, so evaluation of `a` must occur). If you *only* give Haskell the definition, Haskell will not evaluate it.